# Given Two functions find last 4 digits of some value

Tags: calculus

Let
$$P(n) = \sum_{m=1}^\infty \left(\prod_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{m+k}\right)$$
And
$$Q(n) = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{P(k)}$$

Then find the last $4$ digits of $Q(2015)+2015$

Comment: @Alex.R I haven't been able to do anything so far

Comment: @yagnapatel I think I understand

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First we compute $P(n)$ as
$$P(n) = \sum_{m=1}^\infty \left(\prod_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{m+k}\right)$$
$$ P(n) = \sum_{m=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{m\times(m + 1) \times(m+2)\cdots(m+n)}$$
$$ P(n) = \sum_{m=1}^\infty \dfrac{(m-1)!}{(m+n)!}$$
$$ P(n) = \dfrac{1}{n.n!} \sum_{m=1}^\infty \dfrac{(m-1)!n!(m+n - m)}{(m+n)!}$$
$$ P(n) = \dfrac{1}{n.n!} \sum_{m=1}^\infty \dfrac{(m - 1)!n!}{(m+n-1)!} - \dfrac{m!n!}{(m+n)!}$$
$$ P(n) = \dfrac{1}{n.n!}$$

Now, we compute $Q(n)$ as
$$Q(n) = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{P(k)} = \sum_{k=1}^n k.k!$$
We can telescope the above sum as $\Rightarrow k.k! = ((k+1)-1).k! = (k+1)!-k!$
$$\Rightarrow Q(n) = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{P(k)} = \sum_{k=1}^n (k+1)!-k! = 2!-1!+3!-2!+\ldots+(n+1)!-n!$$
And thus,
$$\Rightarrow Q(n) = (n+1)!-1$$
Therefore, now we are just left with computing
$$Q(2015)+2015 \pmod{10000} = 2016! + 2014 \pmod{10000} = 2014$$

*Wherever there is a '.' this means multiply.